# spikes in traffic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, redis

I have a bare bones setup on Amazon, and wanted to know which is the better approach coming out of the gate on a new site, where we anticipate a spike of traffic occasionally (from tech press) before we gradually build up 'real' membership traffic to a reasonable level.

I currently am toying with two starter options:

1) Do I have 1 node app (micro ec2) pointing to a redis-server AND mongod (EC2 server) (which mounts one combined 10G EBS).

Or

2) do I have 1 node app (micro ec2) running redis-server and mongod locally (but with 2 10G EBS mounts, 1 for redis and 1 for mongo).

If traffic went crazy (tech press etc), which is easiest/fastest to scale to handle the spike in traffic. I anticipate equal read writes for mongo and redis btw, and I have no caching (other than that provided by cloudfront assets like images and some css)

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to Redis, but for MongoDB you'll want to be sure that you run on an instance with sufficient RAM to hold your "working set" of data in memory. "Working set" means, roughly, the full set of data that your application accesses frequently -- for instance, consider Twitter -- the working set of Twitter data is the most recent set of status updates across all users, as this is what is shown on web pages and what Twitter provides via its APIs. For your application, the definition of working set may differ.

Mongo uses memory-mapped files for data access, which means that its performance is great when there is enough memory to hold the data you are accessing frequently, and can degrade when there is not. If you expect your data set to grow beyond about 2.5 gigabytes, you will also want to ensure that you are on a 64-bit instance -- on 32-bit instances, Mongo is limited to around 2.5 gigabytes of data, due to the limited memory address space available on such a platform. For more on MongoDB on EC2, see [the Mongo docs on EC2 deployment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2) on the wiki.

I would also caution against using EC2 Micro instances in your production environment. The nature of Micros is that they have "burstable" but very limited CPU resources. If you get a spike of traffic due to tech press, it's likely that your application would be limited by EC2 to a very low amount of available CPU, which will cause performance to suffer. You can mitigate this to a certain extent with load balancing and many Micro instances, but it may be more cost-effective and less complex to simply use Large instances for both Mongo/Redis and your application servers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this question, since IMO, the answer also applies to your situation:

[Benefits of deploying multiple instances for serving/data/cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641784/the-benefits-of-deploying-multiple-instances-for-serving-data-cache/8643299#8643299)

I would never put mongod and redis-server on the same box. MongoDB is meant to swap due to its usage of memory mapped files, and will generate swapping activity if the data cannot fit in RAM. Redis does not use data structures which are compatible with swapping (like MongoDB does with btrees), and will become unresponsive if its memory is swapped out. Currently, there is no easy way to lock Redis in memory.

So I would put Redis and the app server on the same box, and isolate MongoDB on its own box. 
Depending on the size of the data you want to store in Redis, I would pick a large or a small EC2 instance. Redis works well in 32 bits, but memory is limited. For MongoDB, a 64 bits box is almost mandatory. In any case, I would avoid micro instances like the plague.